# How to change coc.nvim floating window colors?

Tags: text-editor, neovim, coc.nvim

I'm using coc.nvim plugin for C++ in my vim editor, here it's showing error but its colors hurt my eyes, I've been searching for solution but still don't know how to customize the colors

[cocnvim floating window color](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xPPQl.png)

Comment: This isn't really a programming question so is off topic for stack overflow

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To choose another background color you can use

```
:highlight CocFloating ctermbg=color
```

And to change the foreground (text) color of the error message use

```
:highlight CocErrorFloat ctermfg=color
```

where `color` is either a color name or a color number (generally from 0 to 15).

To read more on color values

```
:h cterm-colors
```

### GUI

If you want to use a GUI for vim, you should consider using `guibg` and `guifg` arguments in addition to `ctermbg` and `ctermfg`.

`guifg` and `guibg` value is either a color name or a hex-encoded RGB value (ex. `#ff0000` for red).

GUI color values can be found here

```
:h gui-colors
```

Comment: thanks for your solution but mine is just customizing colors right on my terminal, I'm using ConEmu on windows, those colors actually came from this software

Comment: does this go into vimrc? Or into the color file?

Answer (score 2):

In their github Discussion, there is a conversation that can solve all problems with `Coc FloatingWindow`:

[here is the link](https://github.com/neoclide/coc.nvim/discussions/3351)