# How do I persistently change coc.nvim colours from my ~/.config/nvim/init.vim?

Tags: neovim, coc.nvim

I understand that I can change my coc.nvim colours [from inside neovim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180454/how-to-change-coc-nvim-floating-window-colors), but how do I do so permanently from the init.vim file (or otherwise), so that they're changed automatically every time I open the editor?

###### Default colours poor for legibility:

[image]

Comment: https://vi.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution comes from [the stackoverflow post you shared](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64180454/how-to-change-coc-nvim-floating-window-colors), [this vi stackexchange post](https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/23328/change-color-of-coc-suggestion-box) and learning a bit of vimscript with [learning vimscript the hard way](https://learnvimscriptthehardway.stevelosh.com/).

On your `init.vim` file you can write the following:

```
func! s:my_colors_setup() abort
  highlight CocFloating ctermbg=color " For background color
  highlight CocErrorFloat ctermfg=color " For text color
endfunc

augroup colorscheme_coc_setup | au!
  au VimEnter * call s:my_colors_setup()
augroup END
```

This works by calling the [highlight command](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/syntax.html#:highlight) on a function that gets called when vim starts.

`CocErrorFloat` changes the text color for error popups, you could also change warnings, infos and hints with `CocWarningFloat`, `CocInfoFloat` and `CocHintFloat` respectively.

Comment: Seems to work quite well, BUT, I have to `:colorscheme xxxx` at least once to get it working. So I'm still have to interact - it's not automatically done.

Comment: You're right! I didn't know why `ColorScheme` worked. I have `colorscheme vim-monokai-tasty` in my config file. You could add a colorscheme if you'd like, but I found out the event `VimEnter` works automatically, I'll update my answer.